# Writing and Running my first program

Tags: java

I know I'm new and this may seem like a simple question, but I am trying to write my first program. I've looked on dogpile.com which led me to wikihow.com (http://www.wikihow.com/Write-Your-First-Program-in-Java).

I know that I can write a program in notepad and other similar programs, but after I write a code in notepad, what do I do with it? Wikihow told me to go launch it in Command Prompt, but I kept getting error messages stating that the location was wrong or that the command "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

What might I have done wrong? What can I do to fix it? Is this a recommended method for a beginner to learn to code/program? (I am interested in learning Java).

Thank you

Comment: Umm, did you install Java? Also, wikihow (and especially notepad) isn't really what you should be using

Comment: In command prompt, Is the path where you are running the command and the path where you have your java file the same??

Comment: follow these steps: https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: It is always recommended to use an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). There are many around, but for beginners, [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/) might be good, otherwise [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/) and [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) are both very popular.

Comment: no, I haven't installed anything, I'm looking at the files suggested now, thank you

Comment: An IDE is complete preference, but Intellij IDEA is my choice after getting tired of Eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go and download Java here:
2. Go and download the Java JDK here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
3. Go and download Eclipse IDE for Java Developers here: https://eclipse.org/downloads/
4. Then you'll be able to right click the program in Eclipse and click "Run..." or you can click the green "Play"/"Start" button at the top to run your program.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I just edited the post. Just giving him an easier solution.

Comment: Thank you @edwardjiang7, I'm downloading these and will be checking them out within minutes

Comment: @RonSpruytteJr No problem, if you need anymore help let me know by replying to this comment. If this helped you, please accept this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend picking up a good beginner's Java book, such as Head First Java or Core Java. And/or finding a good tutorial online, including the ones from Oracle at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/.

Compiling and running from the command line is a great way to start until you get the basics down. A free editor such as notepad++ will help by providing syntax highlighting. Then you will most likely want to use an IDE such as Eclipse to take advantage of all the features they offer such as code completion, etc.

Comment: This link is helpful, I'm saving this page for future reference, thank you

Comment: Definitely! Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I learnt when I started to learning Java programming before google was even there.

1. Download Java Tutorial that is available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java-tutorial-downloads-2005894.html).
2. Extract tutorial in hard disk and bookmark the page in your favorite browser. If you don't understand how to extract. No worries. Bookmark this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/) to get started.
3. Detailed tutorials [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) to bookmark.